# Java, Create an ARGB BufferedImage from a an int[] array

Tags: java, graphics, opacity, bufferedimage

I want to make a funktion, that takes every pixel and changes it a bit.
after it is changed, I have an array of all the pixels, i want to translate that array back to an image.
What would be the fastest way to do that?

```
byte[] argb = ((DataBufferByte) ii.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        int j = (argb.length / 4);
        int[]intrb = new int[j];

        for(int k = 0; k < j; k++) {

            {

                intrb[k] = (((int) argb[4*k]-0x99 & 0xff) << 24); // alpha
                intrb[k] += ((int) argb[4*k+1] & 0xff); // blue
                intrb[k] += (((int) argb[4*k+2] & 0xff) << 8); // green
                intrb[k] += (((int) argb[4*k+3] & 0xff) << 16); // red
            }



        }

        ii.setRGB(); // this is, where i would translate it back. But it has to be an ARGB version.


        return ii;
```

Comment: You have to implement the function. Go check some APIs about the translation. Tell us what you have tried.

Comment: You can just modify the `argb` array directly.  It appears you don’t need ints at all, since you’re only modifying the alpha byte.

Comment: the problem ist, that the Databuffer is only available as DatabufferInt

Comment: If your data buffer is `DatabufferInt`, your code will throw a `ClassCastException` on the first line. Is that what you are observing?